# No route matches [POST] "/services/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I'm using form object with reform gem to build a service form.

slim form:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @service_form], url: services_path
```

routes:

```
    services_path        GET    /services(.:format)             services#index
                         POST   /services(.:format)             services#create
    new_service_path     GET    /services/novo(.:format)        services#new
    edit_service_path    GET    /services/:id/editar(.:format)  services#edit
    service_path         GET    /services/:id(.:format)         services#show
                         PATCH  /services/:id(.:format)         services#update
                         PUT    /services/:id(.:format)         services#update
```

controller - new action: (ServiceFormObject is the form object class for the service)

```
def new
    service = Service.new        
    @service_form = ServiceFormObject.new(service)
end
```

With all that, I'm getting a No route matches [POST] "/services/new".

I don't know why it's searching for a POST in "/services/new" instead of "/services"

Any solution?

-- Rails 4, Reform, Simple_form, slim --

**UPDATE**

I'm using this same form to edit/update, so the hardcoded URL path is not the ideal solution.

I created this method:

```
 def is_persisted?
     if self.persisted?
       "service/#{@service_form.id}"
     else
       '/services'
     end 
 end
```

And I can use this on url, like this:

```
url: @service_form.is_persisted?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the form to this syntax, does it work?

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @service_form], url:"/services"
```

**EDIT**
@Richard Seviora is correct, a hardcoded path is not ideal.  Try adding "as" to the POST route.

```
post 'services' => 'services#create', as: "create_service"
```

When you run rake routes does the POST have a path?

Comment: That worked! Thanks man! But it's really strange that "url: services_path" doesn't work.

Comment: I'd want to dive into this one and understand why it didn't work before. You should avoid passing in hardcoded URLs to guard against future changes and what not.

Comment: I think that the problem was with the ServiceFormObject object.. but I couldn't get what was the problem..

Comment: Yeah, hardcoded path is not an ideal url value, because I use this same form to edit/update action/view. What I'm trying to do is create a "is_persisted?" method to return the exactly url path (I updated the question..)